# Config::IniFiles hash behaves different than manually written hash

Tags: perl, hash, reference, config

I am loading a config file, which ends up as an embedded hash, with [Config::IniFiles](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Config-IniFiles-2.94/lib/Config/IniFiles.pm). After that, I want to modify the resulting hash by, for some keys, bringing its values one level up. In the example below, I am aiming for this as a result:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'max_childrensubtree' => '7',
          'port' => '1984',
          'user' => 'someuser',
          'password' => 'somepw',
          'max_width' => '20',
          'host' => 'localhost',
          'attrs' => {
                       'subattr2' => 'cat',
                       'topattr1' => 'cat',
                       'subattr2_1' => 'pt',
                       'subattr1' => 'rel'
                     },
          'max_descendants' => '1000'
        };
```

So for the keys `params` and `basex` at the highest level, I want to move its contents (key-value pairs) to the highest level - and remove the items themselves. In short:

```
(
  a => {
    'key1' => 'ok',
    'key2' => 'hello'
  }
)
```

turns into

```
(
  'key1' => 'ok',
  'key2' => 'hello'
)
```

The strange thing is that what I am trying to do does *not* work on a hash built from a read INI file, but it does work with a manually inserted hash. In other words, this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %ini = (
        'params' => {
                      'max_width' => '20',
                      'max_childrensubtree' => '7',
                      'max_descendants' => '1000'
                    },
        'attrs' => {
                     'topattr1' => 'cat',
                     'subattr1' => 'rel',
                     'subattr2' => 'cat',
                     'subattr2_1' => 'pt',
                   },
        'basex' => {
                     'host' => 'localhost',
                     'port' => '1984',
                     'user' => 'someuser',
                     'password' => 'somepw'
                   }
);

&_parse_ini(\%ini);

sub _parse_ini {
  my $ref = shift;

  foreach (('params', 'basex')) {
    foreach my $k (keys %{$ref->{$_}}) {
        $ref->{$k} = $ref->{$_}->{$k};
    }
    delete $ref->{$_};
  }

  print Dumper($ref);
}
```

But this does not:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Config::IniFiles;

# Load config file
tie my %ini, 'Config::IniFiles', (-file => $ARGV[0]);

&_parse_ini(\%ini);

sub _parse_ini {
  my $ref = shift;

  foreach (('params', 'basex')) {
    foreach my $k (keys %{$ref->{$_}}) {
        $ref->{$k} = $ref->{$_}->{$k};
    }
    delete $ref->{$_};
  }

  print Dumper($ref);
}
```

The input ini file for this example would be:

```
[params]
max_width = 20
max_childrensubtree = 7
max_descendants = 1000

[attrs]
topattr1 = cat
subattr1 = rel
subattr2 = cat
subattr2_1 = pt

[basex]
host = localhost
port = 1984
user = admin
password = admin
```

I have been looking in the documentation and on SO for similar issues but have found none. It appears that the hashes are identical (Config::IniFiles doesn't seem to add something specific), so I have no idea why it works for 'manual' hashes, and not for read-in ones.

Comment: Without trying this, I see that there's a `tie`. If you alter the reference to the tied hash that comes out of the Config::IniFiles thing in a way that removes keys on the upper level, you probably break whatever black magic is involved in there. This will likely confuse the hell out of the IniFIles thing that tries to put those things back into the file.

Comment: @simbabque Ah. I wrongly assumed that everything Dumper shows me is the only thing that is going on with the object. I thought that if it were some special IniFiles object, it would be visible in the *dump* of the ref.

Comment: Data::Printer will show that. It does a lot more introspection. Data::Dumper is a serializer, not a debugging tool. Its purpose is to have a reader/writer for machine-readable data structures. It creates the exact textual Perl representation of data structures without compression or encoding. That means you can `eval` them to put them back in. Since it's included with Perl it's the go-to thing for simple debugging. Data::Dump is more concise, but Data::Printer is the real thing for human consumption. Colors, sorting, object introspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two hashes are not identical at all, although they may appear to be from the point of view of the data they contain.

The first one is a regular hash. You can do whatever you like with it.

The second one is a tied hash. It becomes an object of Config::IniFiles, but with a hash like interface. So whilst it appears to be a hash, the package can override the methods for storing or fetching information in the hash however it likes.

In this particular case, it looks like Config::IniFiles will only store a new key value in the hash if the value is hash ref. So you can't flatten out the tied hash as you want. Instead you'll have to create a new hash and copy the data in to it to do what you want.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. At first I thought of this indeed, but I assumed that Dumper would show me if something specific was going on. Could you add an example how I can copy %ini to a none Config::IniFiles object? I assume that if I simply do `my %new = %ini` I still get the same issue?

Comment: @BramVanroy You don't want to do just a `my %new = %ini` though - you can just have your `_parse_ini` function store it into a different hash.

Comment: I understand that, buy my point is: because I don't want to change _every_ key-valur pair in the hash (and thus some stay the same as they were), isn't it more logical to just copy the INI hash after tie-ing AS A HASH (without extra Config::IniFiles sugar), and then do the adjustments in parse_ini on that copy?

Comment: Or you could build the new hash by copying or modifying each key in `%ini` as required. For what it's worth, I believe you won't get anything except a pure hash if you copy it the way you've described above.